# How does stream input work in C++, with cin?

Tags: c++

I am confused what happens when another cin comes does the previous input is flushed?

That is when we hit enter for the next input there is `\n` but what happens to the input?

is it still in the input stream?

Another doubt is, when there is already something in the input stream then it does not take user input so in that case does it assign whatever is there in input stream to the variable? The code is given here

```
string playername,food,age;

cin>>playername;

cout<<"what is your age";

cin>>age;

cout<<"your fav food";

cin>>food;
```

Now if I give `playername` as "rahul singh" it will give "rahul" to the playername but now singh is there in the input stream so does it assign singh to `age`? Or what happens I am not aware

Comment: `cin >> playername` reads one word (delimited by space).

Comment: Use `std::getline` instead of simple `std::cin` if your input contains spaces.

Comment: Yes it's still in the input stream. All input stays there until it is read. Congrats for realising that there's an issue here. Most newbies have no idea.

Comment: yes I know cin will take input till whitespace character..

Comment: did you try to compile and run the code to see the output? Half of you question can be answered this way

Comment: @john My doubt is if its still in the input stream then will it assign singh to age? cause now it will not take user input as there is already something in the stream?

Comment: @Naman Yes if there is some non-whitespace left in the input stream then that will be read and assigned to `age` without waiting for any more user input.

Comment: @john if something is read and assigned than the input stream is cleared automatically? like if singh was left and now singh is assigned to age than what will happen? will singh be cleared automatically from the input stream?

Comment: @Naman Yes once input has been read that input (but no more) is cleared from the input stream (it won't be read again).

Comment: @john thanks u cleared my doubt..One more thing what if age was integer variable then would it skip the input or ask for the input?

Comment: @Naman It would not skip the input, whatever happens the input left behind is the next input to be read. Then only difference that an integer could make is that the read could fail (because the input left behind is not numeric).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am confused what happens when another cin comes does the previous input is flushed?

No, input is not flushed in that case. Everything that was not extracted will still remain in the buffer.

Input buffer *can* be flushed explicitly using `std::cin.ignore(INT_MAX);`.

> so in that case does it assign whatever is there in input stream to the variable?

It will extract from the existing input in the buffer.

> but now singh is there in the input stream so does it assign singh to age?

Yes.

Comment: Okay it means that if something is extracted than the buffer will be flushed? am i right?

Comment: @Naman No. Only the extracted characters are removed from the buffer. Rest of the characters remain in the buffer and can be extracted later.

Comment: What is happening when i am making age to integer and then giving rahul singh as firstname then it wont take anything from the buffer why is this so?Like Rahul is assigned to firstname now singh is there in the buffer and age is integer it cannot take age as input but again lastname is string and singh is still present in the buffer than why it is not assigning singh to lastname?

Comment: @Naman because that's the way the streams have been defined. If you attempt to extract an integer from input that cannot be an integer, then it will not be extracted, and the stream  will be set to failed state.

Comment: Then whatever is present in the input buffer what will happen to it...like after that lastname was to be taken that also is not assigned?like rahul is given to playername after that singh is there in the buffer but integer is to be assigned now no new inputs will be taken after that?? all that is present is useless ?

Comment: @Naman the input will remain in the buffer if extraction fails. No new input is taken until the stream's error state is cleared. The input in the buffer is not necessarily useless.

Comment: Ok got it..that means if extraction error occurs and even if there is input present for other variables it wont extract anything cause the error is occured right?But if no new extraction is done then whatever is present is of no use now? ANd is it possible to clear the error during runtime i mean we have to compile the program again and give the correct inputs then?

Comment: @Naman `it wont extract anything cause the error is occured right?` Right, until the error state is cleared. `whatever is present is of no use now?` Until the error state is cleared. `ANd is it possible to clear the error during runtime` Yes. That is what the `clear` member function does.